# Remove backslash and keep punctuation

Tags: python, string

I have str1: `"I can\'t do that."` How can I get from str1 to str2: `"I can't do that."`?

I have tried `str2 = str1.replace("\", "")` but it doesn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: `replace('\\','')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
str1.replace("\\", "")
```

Comment: I have tried that too, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: In my case all works fine.

Comment: okay, I'll try again. Thank you!